# truth value of empty user-defined data objects

Tags: python, boolean, pydantic, python-dataclasses

This is more of a philosophical question.

In python, `bool([])` evaluates to `False`.
On the other hand, consider the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Lists:
    items: list[str]
    other_items: list[str]


assert bool(Lists(items=[], other_items=[]))
```

The above snippet doesn't raise `AssertionError`.

Why is that?

I encountered a use-case where it seems to make sense to deduce an object's truth value by aggregating the truth values of its attributes.

Are there any caveats to keep in mind before doing so?

(I'm talking about data classes, like `dataclass` or `pydantic.BaseModel`)

Comment: An object always has a "true" value.  Python doesn't/can't look inside it.  You can override this behavior, if you want, using the special `__bool__` method.

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you mean by "an object always has a true value"? Objects like `None`, `[]`, and `0` has the truth value of `False`.
I know the technicalities of `__bool__` - my question is more about why libraries like `pydantic` and `dataclasses` chose to implement it the way they did.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think we have to be careful when talking about "objects" in this context. For example, a string (str) is an "object" that doesn't implement \_\_bool__ and yet is falsey if it represents an empty string

Comment: @CtrlZ Strings have a length: _By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object._ https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: The "why" is because dataclasses would have to make some huge assumptions about your design.  There is precedence for this behavior -- a list that contains two empty lists is not "False".  A dict with an empty key and value is not "False".  This is why you have the `__bool__` option.

Comment: @TimRoberts interesting angle. I agree. I think it's better to stick to this for consistency in terms of objects behavior. For my use case, I'll find a different way to understand whether a data object is "empty". Thank you and everyone for the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of a Python class is always truthy **unless** it implements __bool__() or __len__()

Simple example:

```
class FOO():
    def __init__(self, x:str|None=None):
        self._x = x
    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        return self._x is not None


class BAR:
    def __init__(self, x:str|None=None):
        self._x = x
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 0 if self._x is None else len(self._x)

print(bool(FOO()))
print(bool(FOO("hello")))
print(bool(BAR()))
print(bool(BAR("hello")))
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
False
True
```